# How to move table to a new column using HTML (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to move a portion of my code over to another column. The catch is that the HTML is being generated by an HTML builder using Java. I am confused as to how I can move a table into the next column. (Thanks in advance!)

See image new-b: the text boxed out in blue is what I want to move over.

This is how I am generating my HTML (using java).[image]

```html
<div id="page-wrapper" style="min-height: 502px;">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
         <form role="form">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Environment</td>
                        <td>Demo</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Partner ID</td>
                        <td>asdf</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Merchant Code</td>
                        <td>asdf</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Authentication Header</td>
                        <td>asdf</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div>
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Address 1</td>
                        <td>sdaf</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Address 2</td>
                        <td>faslkj</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>City</td>
                        <td>df</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>State</td>
                        <td>MA</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Zip Code</td>
                        <td>23443</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Country Code</td>
                        <td>US</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>asdljf</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Currency</td>
                        <td>USD</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Store Code</td>
                        <td>12344</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>UTC Off Set</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Uses Daylight Savings?</td>
                        <td>true</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Secondary Identidier</td>
                        <td></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Language</td>
                        <td>ENGLISH</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Latitude</td>
                        <td></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Longitude</td>
                        <td></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Phone</td>
                        <td></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div>
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Attribute Name</td>
                        <td>vkXCVxzv</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Attribute Value</td>
                        <td>dsfj</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Account Type URI</td>
                        <td> sdfas</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Network Type URI</td>
                        <td>svdkm</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Onboarding Tender</td>
                        <td>FDVKM</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Onboarding Gateway</td>
                        <td>FSVK</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Attribute Name</td>
                        <td>cxvXV</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Attribute Value</td>
                        <td>cxvkm</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <br>
      <form role="form" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/ESPortal/On-board"><input type="hidden" name="UI_ACTION" value="ONBOARD_EDIT_LOCATIONOBJECT"><label><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" "="" name="" value="Edit Information"></label></form>
      <form role="form" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/ESPortal/On-board">
         <input type="hidden" name="UI_ACTION" value="ONBOARD_SUBMIT_LOCATIONOBJECT">
         <div align="right"><label><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" "="" name="" value="On-board Location"></label><br>
         </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not idea how to do in java but try to use  <div style="clear:both:display:block;"></div> in html.

Comment: Please remove java tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand that from which object you are getting these values. However, in bootstrap, you can create two columns easily with the following code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <!-- put the table which you want to move the second column -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Probably, the following code will solve your problem (I assumed that the last table contains the information):

```
public String verifyHTML(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        RequestObject requestObject = (RequestObject) request.getSession().getAttribute(ObjectEnum.REQUEST_OBJECT.getValue());
        LocationObject locationObject = requestObject.getLocationObject();
        RequestEnum requestEnum = RequestEnum.ERROR;

        boolean ap =  Boolean.valueOf((String) request.getSession().getAttribute(ObjectEnum.BOOLEAN_AP.getValue()));

        ArrayList<RequestEnum> required = new ArrayList<RequestEnum>();

        if (ap)
            required = requestEnum.requiredAP();
        else
            required = requestEnum.requiredAL();

        LocationEnum locationEnum = LocationEnum.ERROR;
        AttributeEnum attributeEnum = AttributeEnum.ERROR;
        PaymentEnum paymentEnum = PaymentEnum.ERROR;
        RedirectEnum redirectEnum = RedirectEnum.ONBOARD_ACTION_SERVLET;

        PaymentObject paymentObject = new PaymentObject();
        AttributeObject attributeObject = new AttributeObject();

        String html = "<div class=\"row\">" + "<form role=\"form\">"
                + "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6\"><table>";

        for (int i = 0;  i < required.size(); i++)
        {
            requestEnum = (RequestEnum) required.get(i);

            if (requestEnum != RequestEnum.URL_ENDPOINT)
                html = html + "<tr><td>" + requestEnum.getUIValue() + "</td><td>" + requestObject.getInfo(requestEnum) + "</td></tr>";
            else
                html = html + "<tr><td>" + requestEnum.getUIValue() + "</td><td>" + EnvironmentEnum.ERROR.find(requestObject.getInfo(requestEnum)).getUIValue() + "</td></tr>";
        }

        html = html + "</table></div>"
                + "<div><table>";

        for (int i = 0;  i < locationEnum.requiredForm().size(); i++)
        {
            locationEnum = (LocationEnum) locationEnum.requiredForm().get(i);
            html = html + "<tr><td>" + locationEnum.getUIValue() + "</td><td>" + locationObject.getInfo(locationEnum) + "</td></tr>";
        }

        html = html + "</table></div>"
                + "<div><table>";

        for (int i = 0;  i < locationObject.getAttributeObjectArray().size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < attributeEnum.required().size(); j++)
            {
                attributeObject = locationObject.getAttributeObjectArray().get(i);
                attributeEnum = (AttributeEnum) attributeEnum.required().get(j);
                html = html + "<tr><td>" + attributeEnum.getUIValue() + "</td><td>" + attributeObject.getInfo(attributeEnum) + "</td></tr>";
            }

        html = html + "</table></div>";

        for (int i=0; i<locationObject.getPaymentObjectArray().size(); i++)
        {
            paymentObject = locationObject.getPaymentObjectArray().get(i);
            html = html + "<div><table>";

            for (int j = 0; j < paymentEnum.required().size(); j++)
            {
                paymentEnum = (PaymentEnum) paymentEnum.required().get(j);
                html = html + "<tr><td>" + paymentEnum.getUIValue() + "</td><td>" + paymentObject.getInfo(paymentEnum) + "</td></tr>";
            }

            html = html + "</table></div>"
                    + "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6\"><table>";

            for (int n = 0; n < paymentObject.getAttributeObjectArray().size(); n++)
                for (int k = 0; k < attributeEnum.required().size(); k++)
                {
                    attributeObject = paymentObject.getAttributeObjectArray().get(n);
                    attributeEnum = (AttributeEnum) attributeEnum.required().get(k);
                    html = html + "<tr><td>" + attributeEnum.getUIValue() + "</td><td>" + attributeObject.getInfo(attributeEnum) + "</td></tr>";
                }

            html = html + "</table></div>";
        }

        html = html + "</form></div><br>";

        html = html + "<form role=\"form\" method=\"post\" action=\"" + redirectEnum.getValue() + "\">"
                + createInput("hidden", ActionEnum.ACTION.getValue(), ActionEnum.ONBOARD_EDIT_LOCATIONOBJECT.getValue(), false, false)
                + createInput("submit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"", "", "Edit Information", true, false)
                + "</form>";

        html = html + "<form role=\"form\" method=\"post\" action=\"" + redirectEnum.getValue() + "\">"
                + createInput("hidden", ActionEnum.ACTION.getValue(), ActionEnum.ONBOARD_SUBMIT_LOCATIONOBJECT.getValue(), false, false)
                + "<div align=right>"
                + createInput("submit\" class=\"btn btn-success\"", "", "On-board Location", true, false)
                + "</form><br>";


        return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It breaks the output into 4 boxes. I only want to move the last 2 tables. I tried removing the class from the other div tables but it didn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: sorry for the bother. It still didn't work. I uploaded the HTML only (response generated from my Java code). I assume I am not creating tables correctly or something. Is there anyway you could take a look at the updated html only provided in the code section of this question? Thanks!

Comment: Resolved. Your solution worked, I had extra tables I wasn't using. Thanks!